# Adjacency List representation for undirected Graph

Tags: arrays, data-structures, graph

I've got a simple undirected graph with 4 vertices shown below:
[image]
I'm representing it as(adjacency list):
Array indices with Linked nodes:

```
0 -> 1 ->3
1 -> 0 ->2
2 -> 1 ->3
3 -> 0 ->2
```

Now, when I try to do DFS for eg 0 to 1 to 2. what I do:

1. go to 0 index in main array
2. get next ie 1
3. go to main array again to "find" element 1
4. ...and so on

The problem lies in step 3, whenever I need to find next of any node I again need to go to main array and if element's data is any different from its index I'd need to "find" that first element in array. It will get much worse with non-numeric Node data. Any help regarding how not to be needed to "find" a node in main array?

Comment: Use hash table in that case if element's data is different from its index.

Comment: @krpra, but hashtables already have a linked list per bucket in case of collision of hash index. How would they maintain a edges linked list in that case?

Comment: What is the type of data you are planing to store in the linked list. "Adjacency list is an array of LinkedList" is just a concept. Its performance depends on how you have implemented the linkedList.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a data type which associates *keys* with *values*, allowing you to efficiently look up the value associated with any particular key. (In your case, the keys are nodes, and the values are lists of nodes.) This kind of data type is often called a "map", "table", or "dictionary". Popular implementations are [hash tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and [binary search trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree).

For your application, a hash table is likely to be most efficient.

Comment: But I am trying to follow the standard representation of graph which is array of linked nodes commonly called Adjacency List.

Comment: The "adjacency list" representation doesn't necessarily have to be implemented with an array, nor does it require that the lists are linked with pointers. You should think of the adjacency list instead as an [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type). An array of linked nodes is one possible implementation, but (as you have noticed) it is not efficient when the vertices of the graph are non-numeric.

Comment: Unfortunately the terminology here is quite bad. Both terms "array" and "list" are used interchangeably to refer to ADTs and concrete data structures.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with an `array[LinkedList<Node>]`
eg :

```
[0] Node 0 -> Node 1 -> Node 3
[1] Node 1 -> Node 0 -> Node 2
[2] Node 2 -> Node 1 -> Node 3
[3] Node 3 -> Node 0 -> Node 2
```

Now at step 3 you don't have refer the main array, `Node x` will have all the adjecent nodes value in it. Maintain a set of `visited Nodes` if you are applying `dfs`.

Comment: Then, we might not need array at all.